# Echo selected="selected" once form has been submited

Tags: php, forms, echo

I need to echo out **selected="selected"** after form submitting.

```
echo '<form id="myform1" class="myform1" method="GET" name="myform1">';
echo '<select id="SortBy" name="SortBy" onchange="return submitForm1()">';
echo '<option value="" disabled="disabled">Order By</option>';
echo '<option value="RegularPrice">Price</option>';// if selected echo selected="selected"
echo '<option value="MaxGuests">Max Guests</option>';// if selected echo selected="selected"
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Wait what?  You just want to echo:"Selected="selected"?

Comment: exactly after the form has been submitted to keep the option selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

  echo '<option value="RegularPrice"';
  if (isset($_GET['SortBy']) AND $_GET['SortBy'] == 'RegularPrice') {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
  }
  echo '>Price</option>';

?>
```

Comment: Maybe I could find this answer even without posting the question! but it is what I was looking for. Thx.